# No data but only header in AJAX POST for IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, ajax, internet-explorer

So in my scenario I'm using AJAX to send data to server. Here is my AJAX code:

```
$.post('change_password',"username"+username+"password"+$('#Confirm_password').val()+";",function(data,status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  if(status=="success"){
       if(data=="set_success"){ 
            alert("Password Change Success");
       }                        
  }
});
```

I read a lot of articles they say that IE sends the post in 2 tcp packets(1 header and 1 data content). So In my server side If I only do 1 receive I can only get the header but not data content which is what I really need. I try some solution like adding meta tag like

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

But nothing work for me to make IE send the post in only 1 packet instead of 2.

But weird thing is that. In other forums, people say this is a bug for IE10 or 11. But I try to downscale my IE to IE9 it still not working.

Anyone has idea about it? Been stuck in this problem for almost 5 days.

And also, I have my server implement like this:

```
if((err = netconn_recv(conn, &inbuf)) == ERR_OK) {

      netbuf_first(inbuf);

      do{

          netbuf_data(inbuf, (void**)&buf, &buflen);
          strcat(recieve_buffer, buf);
          }while(netbuf_next(inbuf) >= 0);
}
```

So this is an LWIP library for a light-weight tcp/ip. It receive the incoming request by netconn_recv. But it only get the header of the post if I use IE browser. I try to receive the incoming request again. It does sometimes receive "just data content(no header)." but sometimes it get wrong packet(like other requests). I'm just wondering if there is a way to receive that the post in 2 tcp packets?

```
/* for browser like IE. Recieve the netbuf again to get content */
              /*
if(strcmp(http_body,"") == 0){

    if((err = netconn_recv(conn, &inbuf)) == ERR_OK) {
        netbuf_first(inbuf);
        do{
            netbuf_data(inbuf, (void**)&http_body, &buflen);
        }while(netbuf_next(inbuf) >= 0);
    }
    netconn_write(conn,&http_body[0], strlen(http_body), NETCONN_COPY);

}
else{
    netconn_write(conn,&http_body[0], strlen(http_body), NETCONN_COPY);
}
   */
```

Comment: Wouldn't a sufficiently large payload result in multiple TCP packets from *any* browser? If your server-side code is handling data at the packet level I should think you'd always need to wait until you had *all* packets before you had the full *request* that the client code made.

Comment: I know what you mean. But when "netconn_recv" the "netconn_buf" contain all the receive data in "pbuf". And I extract that data out by doing that do-while loop. What I get is only the header of the post.

Comment: Is that C code? Maybe you should add a "c" tag to your question instead of "javascript" and "jquery"...

Comment: Yes, But I just try to find a solution to solve this problem. Either make the IE to send the post that header and data whole together or try to deal with reception of server side.